# How To Read TIF File in Keras ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, deep-learning, resnet

I'm using the ResNet 50 model to classify land cover on Sentinel-2 imagery. I'm modifying this notebook: [Land Cover Classification with EuroSAT Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/code/nilesh789/land-cover-classification-with-eurosat-dataset)

In this case, I use TIF data from Sentinel-2 imagery with size 32x32x3 (3 band RGB 4-3-2).

However, when using the ImageDataGenerator function, the error `UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fe5301bc810>` appears. In my opinion, the error occurs because the data used is TIF, because when I use JPG, there is no such error.

I've tried using the imread function from the tifffile library but it hasn't worked either. Here's my code:

```
# Define a custom function to read TIF images
def read_tif_image(file_path):
    image = imread(file_path)
    return image

# Create ImageDataGenerator instance
train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=60,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True,
    preprocessing_function=read_tif_image,
)

# Set the image data generator's preprocessing function to read TIF images
# train_gen.preprocessing_function = read_tif_image

# Set up the train generator
train_generator = train_gen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=TRAIN_DIR,
    target_size=(64, 64),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode=CLASS_MODE,
    color_mode='rgb',
    shuffle=True,
    seed=69
)

batch_images, batch_labels = next(train_generator)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(batch_images))
for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    ax.imshow(batch_images[i])
    ax.axis('off')
plt.show()

# train resnet
resnet50_history = resnet50_model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=N_STEPS,
    epochs=50,
    callbacks=[early_stop, checkpoint],
    validation_data=test_generator,
    validation_steps=N_VAL_STEPS
)
```

If using the imread function from the tiffffile library, I can successfully read a TIF image, for example like this

```
from tifffile import imread

image = imread('/path/to/file.tif')
print(image)
```

So how do I read the tif image and make the training data for ResNet like my case?

The function to create a Resnet model and the TrainDataGenerator function can read TIF files to be used as training data